# Checking whether a string ends with one of a list of suffixes

Tags: python, strings

I want to check if some line ends with any substring defined in some list. Is there a better way than following one?

```
endsA = ['foo', 'bar', 'fur', 'beer']
endsB = ['door', ... ]

def checkEnds(line, ends):
    for end in ends:
        if line.endswith(end):
            return True

....

if checkEnds(line, endsA):
    do_something()
```

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there is! Generator comprehensions and the `any` function to the rescue.

```
def checkEnds(line, ends):
    return any(line.endswith(end) for end in ends)
```

Just like the original code, this only checks as many `line.endswith(end)` as necessary, returning `True` on the first `True` result.

Comment: Thank you (+1).  I am wondering will `endsWith` perform to each element of `ends` or till first `True`?

Comment: Written in this form, it will stop as soon as possible.

Comment: @SjoerdJobPostmus: That would be a good detail to have as a note in your answer, IMO. +1

Comment: @ZachGates: Added it to the answer instead.

Answer (score 3):

@Sjoerd's solution using `any()` is definitely the way to go.

I'd also like to point out a [recommendation in PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations):

> - Be consistent in return statements. Either all return statements in a function should return an expression, or none of them should. If any return statement returns an expression, any return statements where no value is returned should explicitly state this as `return None`, and an explicit return statement should be present at the end of the function (if reachable).

In your case, this means that if you were to keep your `for` loop, you should also write an explicit `return False` instead of returning `None` by falling off the end of the function.

I would also suggest a better name for your function: `any_suffix_matches(suffixes, string)`.  This name leads to more readable code in the caller, and clearly conveys the idea that the function is a true-false test.  It also conforms to the [PEP 8 naming convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names).

```
if any_suffix_matches(endsA, line):
    do_something()
```

Note that I've also swapped the order of the parameters.  Since "contains any of these suffixes" is the test, and the test is applied to some string, the suffixes should be placed closer to the function name.  You see this design convention in [`re.search(pattern, string)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search), for example.